# adding cache file .appcache stops jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, azure

I have published a website on azure which usues jquery ajax calls to fetch the data from azure hosted database.
Now my question is this flow is working fine unless and until i add ".appcache" file in it for caching the files locally so that the website can work offline as well. After adding this file it stops working and shows me an error like

```
   net::ERR_FAILED                         $jquery-1.11.2.js:9659
   send                                    $jquery-1.11.2.js:9659
   jQuery.extend.ajax                      $jquery-1.11.2.js:9210
   loginservice                            $authentication.js:94
   (anonymous function)                    $authentication.js:81
```

clicking on `"jquery-1.11.2.js:9659"` redirects me to this line in `jquery`:

`xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );`

can somebody please guide me how does this works? how can use caching and jquery together?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the url you are trying to access via jQuery is not one that is listed in the `CACHE` section of your cache manifest. Remember that, when using appcache, all requests load from the cache and not the server. If a resource isn't cached, you'll get net::ERR_FAILED.

The one exception is for resources listed in the `NETWORK` section of the file. Try adding the following to your cache manifest:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

Try again, and see if the error resolves itself.

[This](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) and [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) are excellent resources.